# How to verify that static method throws an exception using AssertJ?

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, static, assertj

When I try to test this method

```
    static void validatePostcode(final String postcode, final String addressLine)
    {
        if(! hasValidPostcode(postcode, addressLine)) {
            throw new InvalidFieldException("Postcode is null or empty ");
        }
    }
```

using the following test

```
    @Test
    public void testThrowsAnException()
    {
        assertThatThrownBy(validatePostcode("", "")).isInstanceOf(InvalidFieldException.class);
    }
```

I get this error message in IntelliJ

> assertThatThrownBy (org.assertj.core.api.ThrowableAssert.ThrowingCallable) in Assertions cannot be applied to (void)

Same thing with `assertThatExceptionOfType`.

Is it possible to test that static method actually throws an unchecked exception using AssertJ? What should I change in my test?

Comment: why would you test it like that? Use an ExpectedException. https://www.baeldung.com/junit-assert-exception

Comment: We use JUnit4 and I know about `@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)` but was looking to do the same using AssertJ.

Comment: @Cybex don't use `@Test(expected = ...)`. It's basically like wrapping the entire method body in a try/catch, so the test "passes" if *anything* in the test throws that exception, not just the thing you intend to test. So, especially for unchecked exceptions, your test can appear to pass even when it's not doing what you think it does.

Comment: @Andy Turner, yeah, this is one of the reasons why I want to switch to AssertJ.

Comment: @Cybex but JUnit 4.13 adds [assertThrows](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,%20org.junit.function.ThrowingRunnable)). No need to, ahem, throw the baby out with the bathwater.

Comment: @Andy Turner Thanks, I'll take a look at it. But I guess for consistency it would be better to stick with one library (AssertJ).

Comment: AssertJ also lets you chain other assertion after `isInstanceOf` like `hasMessage`, see https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-exception-assertions-assertThatThrownBy

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As the compilation error demonstrates, that method expects a throwing callable.

```
@Test
public void testThrowsAnException()
{
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> validatePostcode("", "")).isInstanceOf(InvalidFieldException.class);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

change to this way. you need to pass lambda to test with assertj

```
assertThatThrownBy(()->validatePostcode("","")).isInstanceOf(InvalidFieldException.class);
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Sorry, but answer above was first.